# form.length always returns me 1

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to save in a variable the number of inputs I've have inside my form but always returns me 1.

My HTML code:

```
<form method="post" action="sorteo.php" name="form">
        Participante:<br>
        <input type="text" name="1" class="primero">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Sortear">
        <br><br>
    </form>
```

Then in console I do this:

```
document.form.length
```

But returns me 1. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `document.form.length` returns an error for me, but `document.forms.length` returns 1, the number of forms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the number of elements, than look at the [elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.elements) nodeList

```
document.formName.elements.length
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there is only one form in your page so it returns 1.

You should be checking for inputs:

```
document.form.getElementsByTagName('input').length
```

Or, if you want to count any elements like input textarea, etc. then you can use elements:

```
document.form.elements.length
```

But it doesn't count the element `input` with the type image.

Answer (score 0):

there is only 1 form in the `html` you provided. Also, its `forms`.

To get the inputs use: `document.querySelectorAll('input').length`

Comment: What about select and textareas?

Answer (score -1):

You should use getElementById and give an ID to your element, like

```
<form method="post" action="sorteo.php" name="form" id="form1">
```

then use

```
document.getElementById("form1");
```